# Save .xls file into .txt file in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, xls, save-as

How to save (in fact Save As) .xls file into a text file from C#. I tried `File.Copy()` but I am unable to see data. I am getting some special characters in the text file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot magically convert data from one format to another.  You need an Excel reader

Comment: You will likely to need use a class that provides access to Excel worksheets and the data contained therein. I imagine some assembly like Microsoft.Office or something has such a class.

Comment: Use [EPPLus Library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Please show the code you are trying so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook.SaveAs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method